# Compare two lists or arrays of arbitrary length in C#; order is important

Tags: c#, arrays, list, compare

Say I have two lists or arrays of strings.  For example:

list 1: "a", "c", "b", "d", "f", "e"

list 2: "a", "d", "e", "f", "h"

List 1 and list 2 are of arbitrary lengths.  List 1 may contain elements not in list 2, and visa versa.

I'd like to know when items in list 1 are found in list 2, and more specifically I want to know when an item in list 1 is found in list 2 but is found in a different order than which it is found in list 2, relative to the items in list 2. (Hopefully the example below clarifies this statement).

For example, "a" is found in both lists and is the first item in both lists.  So, everything is okay so far. "c" and "b" are found in only the 1st list and so can be ignored. "h" is found in only the 2nd list and can also therefore be ignored.

"d" is found in both the 1st and 2nd list.  It is found after "a" (the first item) in the original list.  Even though the position within the 1st list is different form the second list, it is is okay because its relative order is the same within the two lists (the second match in common between lists).

In the example above "f" and "e" are in the 'wrong' order in list 1, because "e" comes becomes before "f" in the 2nd list.  So, I would like to report that "e" and "f" are in the wrong order in the first list.  How would I do this?

The solution should be in C#. Thank you!

Comment: I think it would help if you could provide a code example of how you would want to manipulate the results of such a comparison. Right now, the problem may be too open-ended to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Do you have any information about the "right" order of items or is one of the lists the "right one"? Because for your example, you say "f" and "e" are in the wrong order in list 1, but you could also say that they are in the wrong order in list 2.

Comment: The second list is always the "right" one.  But right doesn't mean the lists are equal in terms of either length or exact indexes values being the same; it just means that elements that are in both list have to follow the sequence found in the 2nd list.  I apologize if I implied that the second list was wrong.

Comment: In terms of the results of such a comparison, I'm simply going to be iterating through the list and writing the elements to a log file.

Comment: There might be a flaw in the accepted solution, check my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] list1 = {"a", "c", "b", "d", "f", "e"};
string[] list2 = {"a", "d", "e", "f", "h"};
int i = 0;
var list1a = list1.Intersect(list2).Select(l=> new { item = l, order= i++});
int j = 0;
var list2a = list2.Intersect(list1).Select(l=> new { item = l, order= j++});

var r = from l1 in list1a join l2 in list2a on l1.order equals l2.order
        where l1.item != l2.item
        select new {result=string.Format("position {1} is item [{0}] on list1  but its [{2}] in list2", l1.item, l1.order, l2.item )};

r.Dump();
```

### result

position 2 is item [f] on list1  but its [e] in list2

position 3 is item [e] on list1  but its [f] in list2

Comment: The way I understand this, is it only compares source sequences of equal length and corresponding elements (at equal indexes).  In my case, my two sequences have different lengths and may be considered a match (or OK at any rate) even if elements with different indexes are different, providing the sequences are the same.

Comment: i noticed you weren't interested in comparing the sequences... the query above will produce the desired results .. try running in in LinqPad...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have code, but this should be the two main steps:

- Remove every item that is in one list only (either shorten one of the lists or create a third "clean" list)
- Some kind of diff - search for the first mismatching item and then report every following item until both lists are "synchronized" again.

Perhaps it will even help to clean up both of the lists. Then you can use a pointer for each list, set it to the first item and increase them until there's a mismatch.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the first suggestion (with the two bullet points) but I guess my original problem description wasn't very clear.  Sorry!

What I'm trying right now is to iterate through both lists in a nested manner, to eliminate items not common to either list so that I end up with two new lists (or the original lists both modified) that contain just the content that exists in both lists, in the list original sequence.  I then take these two modified lists & use the pointer to each list idea, increasing the reference location until I find a mismatch (& then I record the mismatch).

Comment: I'd like to give both you & Vasu credit, but it looks like I can only mark one answer as correct. Although both very equally helpful for me :(

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
list1.Intersect(list2).SequenceEquals(list2.Intersect(list1))
```

Comment: I see my problem description wasn't very clear at all.  LBushkin is right in that describing my expected results would've been helpful. (And now I understand why both you and ehosca suggested SequenceEquals -- the assumption being I just want a true/false answer).  But the idea of using Intersect will certainly cut down on some of the code I've written so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Levenshtein distance?  I think the first solution that you have already accepted has a flaw.  It will tell you everything is out of order even if one little thing is inserted:

```
      string[] list1 = { "a", "c", "b", "d", "j", "e", "f" };
      string[] list2 = { "a", "d", "e", "f", "h", "j" };
```

that says that j, e, f are out of order, because the j was inserted.

This points out the problem you face.  There are multiple solutions, even more than one optimal solution, to the problem of what is out of order.  Is the J in order or the e and the f?  Are they all out of order?  There is something called the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) that finds a minimal number of inserts and delete operations necessary to start with set A and end up with set B.  There are multiple best solutions, this just finds one of them.

This following algorithm correctly outputs that in list1, j was inserted and e, f are shifted but still in the correct order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using Math = System.Math;

namespace LevCompareLists {

  class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

      string[] list1 = { "a", "c", "b", "d", "j", "e", "f" };
      string[] list2 = { "a", "d", "e", "f", "h", "j" };

      int?[] aMap21 = Levenshtein(list2, list1);
      int?[] aMap12 = Levenshtein(list1, list2);

    }

    public static int?[] Levenshtein(string[] Src, String[] Dst) {
      // this finds a minimum difference solution of inserts and deletes that maps Src to Dst
      // it returns the map from the perspective of Dst, i.e.:
      //   each element of the return array contains the Src index of the corresponging element in B 
      //   a null value means the element in B was inserted, and never existed in A
      //
      // Given A = {"a", "c", "b", "d", "j", "e", "f"}
      //       B = {"a", "d", "e", "f", "h", "j"};
      //
      // Levenshtein(B, A):
      //  a c b d j e f     <-- A
      //  0     1   2 3     <-- aMap
      //  a     d   e f h j <-- B
      //
      // Levenshtein(A, B):
      //  a     d   e f h j  <-- B   
      //  0     3   5 6      <-- aMap
      //  a c b d j e f      <-- A
      //
      // see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

      int cSrc = Src.Length; //length of s
      int cDst = Dst.Length; //length of t
      if (cSrc == 0 || cDst == 0) return null;

      //**** create the Levenshtein matrix 
      // it has at 1 extra element in each dimension to contain the edges
      int[,] aLev = new int[cSrc + 1, cDst + 1]; // the matrix
      int iSrc, iDst;
      // Load the horizontal and vertical edges
      for (iSrc = 0; iSrc <= cSrc; aLev[iSrc, 0] = iSrc++) ;
      for (iDst = 0; iDst <= cDst; aLev[0, iDst] = iDst++) ;
      // load the interior
      for (iSrc = 1; iSrc <= cSrc; iSrc++)
        for (iDst = 1; iDst <= cDst; iDst++)
          aLev[iSrc, iDst] = Math.Min(Math.Min(aLev[iSrc - 1, iDst] + 1, aLev[iSrc, iDst - 1] + 1),
           aLev[iSrc - 1, iDst - 1] + ((Dst[iDst - 1] == Src[iSrc - 1]) ? 0 : 2));

      DumpLevMatrix(aLev, Src, Dst);  // Debug

      //**** create the return map, using the Levenshtein matrix
      int?[] aMap = new int?[cDst];  // this is the return map
      iSrc = cSrc;  // start in lower right corner of the Levenshtein matrix
      iDst = cDst;  // start in lower right corner of the Levenshtein matrix
      // work backwards to pick best solution
      while ((iSrc >= 0) || (iDst >= 0)) {
        if ((iSrc > 0) && (iDst > 0)) {
          // enter here if iSrc and iDst are in the lev matrix and not on its edge
          int nCur = aLev[iSrc, iDst];
          int nIns = nCur - aLev[iSrc, iDst - 1];  // if move along B to find match, it was an insert
          int nDel = nCur - aLev[iSrc - 1, iDst];  // if move along A to find match, it was a deletion
          if (nIns == 1)                 // this char was NOT in A, but was inserted into B
            iDst--;                         //   Leave map of B[j] to nowher, scan to previous B (--j)
          else if (nDel == 1)            // this char was in A, but is missing in B
            iSrc--;                         //   Don't map any B, scan to previous A (--i)
          else                           // Match
            aMap[iDst-- - 1] = iSrc-- - 1;       //   After map B[j] to A[i], scan to prev A,B (--i, --j)
        } else {
          if (iDst > 0)       // remaining chars are inserts, Leave map of B[j] to nowher, scan to previous B (--j)
            iDst--;
          else if (iSrc > 0)  // Delete to the end, deletes do nothing
            iSrc--;
          else
            break;
        }
      }

      DumpMap(aMap, Dst); // Debug

      return aMap;

    }

    // just for debugging
    static void DumpLevMatrix(int[,] aLev, string[] Src, string[] Dst) {

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int cSrc = Src.Length;
      int cDst = Dst.Length;
      int iSrc, iDst;
      sb.Length = 6;
      for (iDst = 0; iDst < cDst; ++iDst)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,-3}", Dst[iDst]);
      Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
      for (iSrc = 0; iSrc <= cSrc; ++iSrc) {
        if (iSrc == 0)
          sb.Length = 3;
        else {
          sb.Length = 0;
          sb.AppendFormat("{0,-3}", Src[iSrc - 1]);
        }
        for (iDst = 0; iDst <= cDst; ++iDst)
          sb.AppendFormat("{0:00}", aLev[iSrc, iDst]).Append(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
      }

    }

    // just for debugging
    static void DumpMap(int?[] aMap, string[] Dst) {

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int iMap = 0; iMap < aMap.Length; ++iMap)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0,-3}", Dst[iMap]);  // dst and map are same size
      Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
      sb.Length = 0;
      for (int iMap = 0; iMap < aMap.Length; ++iMap)
        if (aMap[iMap] == null)
          sb.Append("   ");
        else
          sb.AppendFormat("{0:00}", aMap[iMap]).Append(" ");
      Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string[] list1 = { "a", "c", "b", "d", "f", "e" };
string[] list2 = { "a", "d", "e", "f", "h" };

var indexedList1 = list1.Select((x, i) => new
{
    Index = i,
    Item = x
});

var indexedList2 = list2.Select((x, i) => new
    {
        Index = i,
        Item = x
    });

var intersectedWithIndexes = indexedList2
    .Join(indexedList1,
          x => x.Item,
          y => y.Item,
          (x, y) => new
        {
            ExpectedIndex = x.Index,
            ActualIndex = y.Index,
            x.Item
        })
    .Where(x => x.ActualIndex != x.ExpectedIndex)
    .ToArray();

var outOfOrder = intersectedWithIndexes
    .Select((x, i) => new
        {
            Item = x,
            index = i
        })
    .Skip(1)
    .Where(x => x.Item.ActualIndex < intersectedWithIndexes[x.index - 1].ActualIndex ||
            x.Item.ExpectedIndex < intersectedWithIndexes[x.index - 1].ExpectedIndex)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            ExpectedBefore = x.Item,
            ExpectedAfter = intersectedWithIndexes[x.index - 1]
        });

foreach (var item in outOfOrder)
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' and '{1}' are out of order at index {2}",
              item.ExpectedBefore.Item,
              item.ExpectedAfter.Item,
              item.ExpectedBefore.ActualIndex);
}
```

output:

```
'f' and 'e' are out of order at index 4
```